# MPPT SMD diode identification

Tags: pcb, mppt

What kind of diode is this (marked with D35)?
It is from a MidniteClassic 150 MPPT.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's [US1D](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88768/us1.pdf) from Vishay (formerly General Semiconductor - see the GS logo on top).